# Is this notation inconsistent? If not, can some explain why not?

Tags: kinematics, differentiation, notation, calculus

Im working through a textbook section on particle kinematics. An example given is relating vertical velocity to horizontal velocity and states:

$y$ has a constant velocity of $10 \ \rm [m/s]$

$y=(0.001x^2)\ \rm [m]$

when $y=100\ \rm [m]$ then $x=316.2\ \rm [m]$ and $t=10 \ \rm [s]$

Here comes my problem. The book states exactly this:

$v_y=y'=\frac{d}{dt}(0.001x^2)=(0.002x)x'=0.002xv_x$

My problem is that $x'$ seems to have either appeared from nowhere or been omitted in the first stages.
$\frac{d}{dt}(0.001x^2)=0.002x$ not $(0.002x)x'$

To me this seems sloppy or inconsistent. I keep running into little problems like this throughout this book and then waste time trying to figure out what's going on. It also erodes my trust in what I'm reading .

Can anyone offer some insight into this?

Comment: $x'$ just means $\frac{dx}{dt}$ since it changes with time so it has a derivative wrt to time. Recall Chain rule.

Comment: Chain rule ${d}/{dx}(f(g(x)))=(f'(g(x)))(g'(x))$

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost This should really be an answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are getting confused with derivatives. You write:

$$\frac{d}{d\color{red}t} (0.001 x^2) = 0.002 x\,, \tag{1}$$

but this is wrong. It would be true if the derivative was with respect to $x$, i.e.:

$$\frac{d}{{d\color{red}x}} (0.001 x^2) = 0.002 x\,. \tag{2}$$

Here you have to take a derivative with respect to the time $t$, and for that you have to use the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule), which states:

$$\frac{d}{dt} f(g(t)) = f'(g(t)) g'(t)\,, \tag{3}$$

where the notation $f'$ means *derivative with respect to the argument of the function*, or more concretely:

$$f'(g(t)) = \frac{d}{dg(t)} f(g(t))\,, \qquad g'(t) = \frac{d}{dt} g(t)\,. \tag{3}$$

In your example $x'$ is a common shorthand notation that means:

$$x' := \frac{d}{dt} x(t)\,, \tag{4}$$

and the derivative of the *position* $x$ with respect to the time $t$ is the velocity $v$ (note that the notation $\dot{x}$ is also often used for denoting derivatives with respect to time). It is a sensible operation to do, as this derivative means the *change in position as time passes by*, which is a function you are usually eager to know in physics.

In your case the functions $f$ and $g$ presented in the chain rule above would be:

$$f(x) = x^2\,, \qquad g(t) = x(t)\,, \tag{5}$$

which result the following derivatives:

$$f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} x^2 = 2 x\,, \qquad g'(t) = \frac{d}{dt} x(t) = x'(t)\,. \tag{6}$$

And you should find:

$$\begin{align} y' &= \frac{d}{dt} (x(t))^2 \\ &= \frac{d}{d (x(t))} (x(t))^2 \frac{d}{dt} x(t) \\ &= 2 x(t) x'(t)\,. \tag{7} \end{align}$$

(I have omitted the $0.001$ prefactor for clarity. I have also written $x(t)$ everywhere to emphasise the fact that $x$ is really a function of time, but if it bothers you you can remove the $(t)$ as long as you don't forget that this dependence is there!)

Hope this helps! Otherwise here is a [good source](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-calculus/dc-chain) for reviewing the chain rule.

Comment: Ooo fancy color in MathJax... :-)

Answer (score 1):

This comes from the chain rule.

Your $y$ expression is expressed as a function of $x$. However, both $x$ and $y$ depend on time. Therefore, it can be written that:

$$y(t)=\left( x(t) \right)^2$$

I omitted your constant for readability.

Then, by the chain rule,

$$\dfrac{\rm d}{\mathrm dt}y(t)=\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\left( x(t) \right)^2 = 2x(t)\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} x(t) =2xx'$$